# How to change option menu icon in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-optionsmenu, android-icons

How to change the index icon of option menu?

[image]

I mean icon (3).

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

    return true;
}
```

And here is the XML file:

```
<item android:id="@+id/Bugreport"
    android:title="@string/option_bugreport" />

<item android:id="@+id/Info"
    android:title="@string/option_info" />

<item android:id="@+id/About"
    android:title="@string/option_about" />
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The following lines should be updated in **app -> main -> res -> values -> Styles.xml**

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<!-- Style to replace actionbar overflow icon. set item 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle' in AppTheme -->
<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
</style>
```

This is how it can be done. If you want to change the overflow icon in action bar

Comment: @smartmouse let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Worked, thank you so much! What's the need of "Lala" in contentDescription?

Comment: you welcome, i am glad to help you and actually there is no such need for that but with every image we give description for that that is why i used it, and 'lala' means good friend in my language ;)

Comment: This also works when using [Material theme via AppCompat](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/): just switch to  `parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow"` in MyActionButtonOverflow.

Comment: not working in using mipmap instead of drawable/ic_launcher.. using api 15 appcompat theme

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't work for me. No errors but the icon remains the same.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you for amazing solution... Solution still works in 2019

Comment: How can we change option menu icon at runtime?

Comment: Do you know how to make it valid for just one menu file , and not for all of the menus in the app ?

Answer (score 65):

I got a simpler solution which worked perfectly for me :

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.change_pass);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

Comment: for me also it worked fine and programmatic way, we can change it any time that is the added advantage. Thanks Parth.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: This is just so perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Most of people have discussed changing the icon forever for whole app.

Comment: doesn't work when using `val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.action_bar)`
       , `toolbar.overflowIcon = Util.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu)`, `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 12):

1) Declare `menu` in your class.

```
private Menu menu;
```

2) In `onCreateOptionsMenu` do the following :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_orders_screen, menu);
    return true;
}
```

3) In `onOptionsItemSelected`, get the item and do the changes as required(icon, text, colour, background)

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.ventor_status) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_settings_online) {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.history_converted));
        menu.getItem(1).setTitle("Online");
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_settings_offline) {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cross));
        menu.getItem(1).setTitle("Offline");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

> **Note**:
>   
>  If you have 3 menu items : 
>  menu.getItem(0) = 1 item,
>  menu.getItem(1) = 2 iteam, 
>  menu.getItem(2) = 3 item

Based on this make the changes accordingly as per your requirement.

Comment: He's talking about the menu icon itself, not the menu items.

Comment: Instead of menu.getItem(0), I recommend using menu.findItem(R.id.viewId) because the for the former become a mess once you have so many items and their position if you make one of the option invisible.

Answer (score 12):

```
//just edit menu.xml file    
//add icon for item which will change default setting icon
//add sub menus


 ///menu.xml file


    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
            app:showAsAction="always" >

            <menu>

                <item android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
                    android:title="menu 1" />

                <item android:id="@+id/action_menu2"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
                    android:title="menu 2" />

            </menu>
        </item>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) Just want to mention that the item of "action_settings" should be wrapped in    "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >  ...  </menu>"

Comment: `@string/action_settings` - there must be default android resources for this which includes all languages

Answer (score 6):

This works properly in my case:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                                              R.drawable.change_pass);
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

Comment: doesn't work when using `val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.action_bar)`
       , `toolbar.overflowIcon = Util.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu)`, `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 4):

Use the example of Syed Raza Mehdi and add on the `Application theme` the `name=actionOverflowButtonStyle` parameter for compatibility.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>

    <!-- For compatibility -->
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by doing

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menus"
    android:actionProviderClass="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always">
  <item android:id="@+id/Bugreport"
   android:title="@string/option_bugreport" />

  <item android:id="@+id/Info"
  android:title="@string/option_info" />

 <item android:id="@+id/About"
   android:title="@string/option_about" />
  </item>
```

Comment: Calling that a hack is kind of misleading. That's a standard part of the Android system.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, this is the correct answer. But it is definitely not a hack.

Answer (score 3):

this work for me, just set your xml menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:title="menu"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:title="menu 1" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_menu2"
                android:orderInCategory="2"
                android:title="menu 2" />

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your custom overflow icon of Actionbar in styles.xml

   ```
    <resources>
       <!-- Base application theme. -->
       <style name=“MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
          <!-- Pointer to Overflow style DONT forget! -->
          <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverFlow</item>
       </style>

       <!-- Styles -->
       <style name="MyOverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
           <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_your_action_overflow</item>
       </style>
    </resources>
   ```
2. Put custom theme "MyTheme" in application tag of AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <application
       android:name="com.example.android.MainApp"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   </application>
   ```

Have fun.@.@

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change icon/title menu in the actionbar/toolbar programmatically,

STEP by STEP

1. Declare Menu in class

> private var mMenu: Menu? = null

2. Overide onCreateOptionsMenu method and find item so you need to change

   ```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
   mMenu = menu
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
   if (mIsFavorite){
       mMenu?.findItem(R.id.action_favorite)?.icon = yourDrawable
   } else {
       mMenu?.findItem(R.id.action_favorite)?.icon = yourDrawable
   }
   return true
   ```

   }
3. Use invalidateOptionsMenu() to update some changes in menu after onCreateOptionsMenu executed. This method will re-create menu

Answer (score 1):

> **Check this out this may work: (in kotlin)**
>
> ```
> toolBar.menu.getItem(indexNumber).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_myIcon)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

An short and easy way to change color of option menu index icon is:

```
<!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/optionMenuIconColor</item>
```

Add above line of code into **style**.xml (custom theme) file,
Hope you get answer,Thanks.

Comment: Even if it works, this is a stupid thing to do; it changes the actual secondary app's text color, used in a multitude of places and widgets as a - you guessed it - text color.

Comment: @Adrian Cretu yeah, that might be stupid if you weren't trying to match the text and icon color, globally.  Otherwise it seems easy and very reasonable.

Comment: we're talking about icon, not color, and you answer will change color of many items

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"
            android:title="Log Out"
            app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

This did the trick for me!