# Icon istead of three dots Android Menu

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to do a menu with only one icon, but instead of that icon, i am getting the typican three dots, and inside my option. So, i only want one icon. That is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.bartek.gestionpea.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ayuda"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="Ayuda"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Here goes my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PeniaSQLiteHelper usdbh;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getActionBar().setTitle("GESTION");

        Button btnCrearPena = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncrearpena);

        btnCrearPena.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CrearNueva.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.ayuda:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the standard Activity, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ayuda"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="Ayuda"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tryed that code right now, and stil dont work. I have tryed almost everything inside the showAsAction, and i only see the 3 dots with my options inside. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you please post the code of your Activity class? You can directly edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Done, alredy psoted my class. ;)

Comment: The same that i have said to CommonsWare, if i do android:showAsAction i get an error who says "should use app:showAsAction".

Comment: It's not an error, you can build anyway. You have this warning because you referenced appcompat-v7 but you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using some things for the native action bar (e.g., inheriting from `Activity`) and some things for the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport (e.g., `app:showAsAction`). **Choose one** and stick with it:

- If you wish to use the native action bar, use `android:showAsAction`
- If you wish to use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, inherit from `AppCompatActivity` (in the latest `appcompat-v7`) or `ActionBarActivity` (for prior versions of `appcompat-v7`)

Comment: If i write android:showAsAction i get an error who says "should use app:showAsAction", so, i dont know really what to do. Thanks for the answer anyway mate :)

Comment: @Uat: If you want to use the native action bar, also get rid of your `appcompat-v7` dependency and anything else that is using it (e.g., your activity theme). Again, you need to choose **one** implementation of the action bar **and stick with it**, not mix and match from multiple implementations.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help! I cant give you votes because i dont have so much reputation yet, but thanks anyway :))

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the app theme (in themes.xml):

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<!-- Style to replace actionbar overflow icon. set item 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle' in AppTheme -->
<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_icon_here</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"options"</item>
</style>
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300480/how-to-change-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using appcompat themes, you sometimes need to set xml attibutes twice:

once with and once without the android namespace

```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```