# how to create Android Burger Button with options icon?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Creating a burger button with multiple customized options in android. When I click the button, I want it to show options with the corresponding icons (shown in the image).

[image: I want the burger button to look like this]

I used Popupmenu but how to set icons in popupmenu options?

Please Help me??

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: do u want it to be added in actionbar or without actionbar?

Comment: i want make option button same as shown in fig.

Comment: You can use pop up menu with custom adapter for icons with text. And for that hamburger icon, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300480/how-to-change-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar

Comment: @Neha without actionbar

Comment: @priyankvex i want add burger button in my UI... m nt using ActionBar

Comment: Then just use the hamburger icon (.png file you can get) for image button or clickable image view.

Comment: @priyankvex but how to show options(Just like menu options) with icon.

Comment: For that use pop-up menu. You can create custom list row item for pop-up menu. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html  Try this. I will post code sample in answer when i'll be free.

Comment: Okay @priyankvex i will try Image button with popupmenu

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ListPopUpWindow and anchor it to the burger button (in case you aren't using actionbar)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

```
String [] items = new String[]{"Item1" , "Item2", "Item3"};

View anchor= (Button)findViewById(R.id.BurgerButton);

 anchor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     showpopup();

});


public void showpopup()
{


ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(this);
//Replace this  adapter with a custom adapter and layout for a custom menu item
popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,items));
popup.setAnchorView(anchor);
popup.setWidth(200);
popup.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
popup_menu

```
    <menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/one"  
            android:title="One"
            android:icon="@drawable:ic_launcher"/>  

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/two"  
            android:title="Two"/>  

        <item  
            android:id="@+id/three"  
            android:title="Three"/>  

    </menu>
```

In your activity on button click add this:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method
```

Hope it helps :)

For menu icon to show add:

```
// Force icons to show
                Object menuHelper;
                Class[] argTypes;
                try {
                    Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                    fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
                    menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popup);
                    argTypes = new Class[] { boolean.class };
                    menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Possible exceptions are NoSuchMethodError and NoSuchFieldError
                    //
                    // In either case, an exception indicates something is wrong with the reflection code, or the
                    // structure of the PopupMenu class or its dependencies has changed.
                    //
                    // These exceptions should never happen since we're shipping the AppCompat library in our own apk,
                    // but in the case that they do, we simply can't force icons to display, so log the error and
                    // show the menu normally.

                    Log.w("error", "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
                    popup.show();
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: i already try this code.... i want options with icon how can i give icon in menu item i also put android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_star" but not show icon

Comment: yup this code work but i want popup option with icon.