# Change Icon from home Button in OptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //action
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

How can I change the Icon from the Back Button (android.R.id.home) in OptionsMenu?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change option menu icon in the action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300480/how-to-change-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_converted));
        break;
}
```

Here `menu.getItem(0)` will the first menu, it should behave accordingly.