# How to change overflow menu icon with imageview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have an toolbar with overflow menu icon with menu items. I need to change the overflow icon to the circular imageview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the code looks like.

```
   Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   CircleImageView mciv = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);
```

I have tried to change the overflow icon but most of SO mentioned about of using drawable. But i need to use the imageview. I have tried with the below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       item.setActionView(mciv);
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But its not working. How to change overflow menu icon with imageview?

Comment: Please post some screen shot of your view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9653007/3967525 check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set click event of imageview and on click open menu.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

or you can manually create Popup menu, [here is the example for popup menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu)