# How do I access the default ToolBar from an Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin, toolbar

I'm trying to access the default [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) from within and Activity's **onCreateOptionsMenu** function to change the Overflow menu icon (three dots icon). I want to use the **setOverflowIcon** method provided by this class.

I have read the official documentation, posts on StackOverflow and other websites and everything fails.

I tried for example **Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);** but I get an error that says that **R.id.toolbar** doesn't exist.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790508/how-to-change-android-overflow-menu-icon

Comment: Can you paste your code, So that I can check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `AppcompatActivity`, you should use `SupportActionBar` like this:

```
supportActionBar?.title = "My Activity title"
```

this piece of code: `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` only works when you've added a `Toolbar` with `toolbar` id in `xml`. even if you did it, you should `setSupportActionBar(yourToolBar)` before doing anything. Then use `supportActionBar` directly instead.

Comment: But this returns an ActionBar instead of ToolBar.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party but default toolbar can be referenced by an id like *androidx.appcompat.R.id.action_bar*

```
findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.action_bar)
```

Answer (score 3):

Performing **Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)** isn't expected to work because the ID does not explicitly exist. Every activity-Java class extends Activity (or its direct or indirect subclasses), you can use this to get the action bar (so to speak).

If your java file extends AppCompatActivity, you can use `getSupportActionBar()` to summon the ActionBar.

Java files that extend Activity require `getActionBar()` to summon the toolbar.

You can thereafter perform operations like changing the displayed text/title, background drawable, amongst other tasks.

To learn more about getting the action bar, check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html).

Comment: But this returns an ActionBar instead of ToolBar.

Answer (score -3):

you can get default toolbar from AppCompatActivity

getSupportActionBar();

Comment: why did you add new answer, just update (edit) previous one

Comment: But this returns an ActionBar instead of ToolBar.

Answer (score -3):

create menu file using xml and place it in res/menu folder

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}
```