# How to display option menu without three dots android? Need to remove three dot menu and display option menu at bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

Usual behaviour:

When we create option, we usually have three dots and when we click three dots button, option menu will be displayed. I have button on bottom too. When I click the button, option menu is displaying

My Requirement:

When we create option, how to display option menu **without three dots**. Because I have button on bottom and when I click the button , option menu is diplaying. But I need to remove only three dots.(hamberger menu) because my requirement is, I need to use older type where menu is present in bottom and when we click the bottom menu,it display overflow menu in androidxappcompat activity.

**Update:**
I used getSupportActionBar() to hide the menu. But I need to move the option menu at bottom.

```
 needsMenuKey = appliInfo.metaData.getBoolean("com.package.name");
                Log.i("MainActivity", "needsMenuKey[" + needsMenuKey + "]");
                if (needsMenuKey) {
                    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    }
```

Comment: What do you want to see instead of three dots? And I'm not sure whether you're talking about the ≡ (hamburger) or … (three dots) button since you mention both as if they're the same thing. In general, you have more control over the App Bar behavior if you use a Toolbar in your view layout instead of the native Action Bar.

Comment: I don't want to show three dots menu. Instead I have button in bottom. So when I click button, it should display overflow menu options.

Comment: there is difference between three dots and ham burger... ham burger is also we can say as ``side menu`` and three dots is something that belong to ``option menu``  which is on the top right corner of appBar or toolbar, when you press it drop down menu appears where you select any option, now mention which one your talking about? and what is bottom? you mean bottom navigation?

Comment: drop down menu to be displayed at bottom and three option should be disappear. Attached the screenshot. Currently it's displaying at top left side.

Comment: Do you want to place this gauge icon on the system bottom navigation bar?

Comment: @Zain I already placed. But when I click the gauge icon, I need to display overflow menu in bottom. Currently it's displaying in top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use NoActionBar Theme or should override onCreateOptionsMenu() and return false without calling super.onCreateOptionsMenu(). I hope one of these solutions will work for you. If yes, do mark this as answer.

Comment: Even when option menu is available?

Comment: @Shadow You are creating a menu using XML Resources right ? So inflate the menu inside your own function and display it when your button is clicked. By doing so, you don't need to depend on the Activity to inflate the Menu for you. When the activity doesn't inflate the menu, the three dot indicator won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

So, to wrap-up the requirements:

- Removing the three dots icon from the top. Instead, having a bottom button that shows the overflow options menu.
- Anchor the options overflow menu to the bottom (instead of the top) when the bottom button is hit.

The system overflow options menu should be anchored to the actionBar/toolBar that hosts it; and therefore you can't show this menu at bottom unless you move this bar to the bottom too. Otherwise you need to create a customized popup menu rather than the system one.

So, the solution here is to create a customized `Toolbar` at the bottom of the activity:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this requires to use a `NoActionBar` theme at `themes.xml` or `styles.xml` such as:
`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`.

And set the new `supportActionBar` in behavior:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        title = ""

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

}
```

[image]

This fulfills the top mentioned requirements apart from that the new `supportActionBar` is now at the bottom, so you probably need to add another toolbar at the top to be customized as you want.

In order to replace the three-dots icon at the bottom with a gauge icon, there are [multiple answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790508/how-to-change-android-overflow-menu-icon), and here is a one:

Add the below style:

```
<style name="customoverflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24</item>
</style>
```

Apply it to the main theme:

```
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/customoverflow</item>
```

You can also add a `paddingEnd` to the `toolBar` to have some space between the icon and the far end of the screen:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"/>
```

[image]